# Clear Glass on Transparent Background

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, lighting, glass

What is the best setup for rendering a realistic-looking, clear glass bottle with transparent background in Cycles?

I am not getting the correct refraction, light reflections and etc and my bottle looks really flat, unrealistic and with strong white silhouettes.

Is there an optimal material setup, lighting setup or anything else that might help?

Thanks!

Comment: hello, maybe show your 3D scene, the material setup, maybe even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi :). Shooting glass is mostly about a lighting setup. Rendering in Cycles has many similarities to actual photography

Comment: @moonboots Unfortunately I cannot upload the file as it exceeds the size limit for that website :/ I was just wondering how to get good illumination on the bottle, without having too strong reflection rings and line on the glass...I forgot to also add that I have to render this in Orthographic front view, which def makes it harder to work with the light paths/rays..

Comment: at least show a screenshot so that we can see what kind of problem you are talking about? but you can share on another platform

Comment: you should not ask "opioned based" questions. These kind of questions will be closed soon. Maybe read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: There is no optimal material setup and the lighting depends a great deal on what you want to accomplish in the scene.  as @JachymMichal says it's very much like setting up lighting in photography.  Take a look at [this post](https://karltayloreducation.com/bottle-product-photography/) to get an idea of what works and why it works.